# Spark dataset join as tuple of case classes

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am joining two datasets where some of their columns share the same name.  I would like the output to be tuples of two case classes, each representing their respective dataset.

```
joined = dataset1.as("ds1")
.join(dataset2.as("ds2"),dataset1("key") === dataset2("key"),"inner")
// select doesn't work because of the columns which have similar names
.select("ds1.*,ds2.*)
// skipping select and going straight here doesn't work because of the same problem
.as[Tuple2(caseclass1,caseclass2)]
```

What code is needed to let spark know to map ds1.* to type caseclass1 and ds2.* to caseclass2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `struct` function here as follows:

```scala
// create a wrapper case class
case class Outer(caseclass1: Caseclass1, caseclass2: Caseclass2)

// join and select the columns as struct
val joined = dataset1.as("ds1")
.join(dataset2.as("ds2"), dataset1("key") === dataset2("key"), "inner")
.select(struct("ds1.*").as("caseclass1"), struct("ds2.*").as("caseclass2"))
.as[Outer]
```

Comment: ```.select[caseclass1,caseclass2](struct("ds1.*").as[caseclass1],struct("ds2.*").as[caseclass2])
.as[Tuple2(caseclass1,caseclass2)]```

Comment: your example code does not compile.  Can you please update with my comment, for those that follow?  And thanks, pointing out ```struct``` gave me a great solution.